# Dismiss Modal View from uitabbarController view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I presented a modal view where the presented view contains a tabbar controller.The view is displayed correctly,but when I add the dismissModalViewController to a button in tabbar viewController,it is not dismissing.Nothing is happening to the view.

How could I dismiss that modal view Controller?

Comment: How do you dismiss it? `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion: nil]` is my best guess on this. note that you should use `dismissViewController` and `presentViewController` instead of `...ModalViewController` since they are deprecated in iOS 5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presenting view controller should be the one handling the dismissal of the modal view controller as well. You should use a delegate to notify the presenting view controller that it can dismiss the view controller it presented:

In the modal view controller:

```
@protocol SomeProtocol<NSObject>
- (void)didFinishDoingWhatItNeedsToDo:(id)sender;
@end

@interface ModalViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <SomeProtocol> delegate;
@end

@implementation

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

    [self.delegate didFinishDoingWhatItNeedsToDo:self];

}
```

Then in the presenting view controller:

```
@interface SomeObject : UIViewController <SomeDelegate>
@end

@implementation

- (void)someMethod {

    ModalViewController *mvc = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];
    mvc.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:mvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)didFinishDoingWhatItNeedsToDo:(id)sender {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you were presenting the controller with tabbar, you must have used :

```
[self presentModalViewController:newTabBarController animated:YES];
```

so when you want to dimiss you have to say,

```
[self.tabBarController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Why would you want to dismiss the `parentViewController`?