# iOS view controller memory not released after it's been dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, automatic-ref-counting

When the user clicks a button it presents a new tab bar view controller with two view controllers. Here's how I do that

```
ACLevelDownloadController *dvc = [[ACLevelDownloadController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ACLevelDownloadController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
ACInstalledLevelsController *ivc = [[ACInstalledLevelsController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ACInstalledLevelsController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UITabBarController *control = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
control.viewControllers = @[dvc, ivc];
dvc.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemFeatured tag:0];
ivc.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemDownloads tag:1];
[self presentViewController:control animated:YES completion:nil];
```

this works fine. I dismiss that view controller with a `dismiss` method in both the `ACLevelDownloadController` and `ACInstalledLevelsController`. That also works fine. What's strange is that the memory usage goes up when I present the view controller
[image]

but it never goes back down. If I present it again, it goes up even more
[image]
I'm using ARC. Why is the memory that the view controllers use not being released after they are dismissed?

### EDIT

The way they are dismissed is both `ACLevelDownloadController` and `ACInstalledLevelsController` have IBActions hooked up that call this method when they are clicked

```
- (void)dismiss:(id)sender{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: can you provide the code you use for dismissing?

Comment: can you try to call the `dismiss...` method on `self.presentingViewController` instead that on `self`?

Comment: Are you using blocks in some part of `ACLevelDownloadController` or `ACInstalledLevelsController`? If so, could you provide us the code for those blocks?

Comment: There are no blocks in either

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944687/dismiss-modal-view-from-uitabbarcontroller-view

Comment: @stosha using a delegate had no impact

Comment: this is killing me too. I can not figure out why it's not releasing everything.

Comment: Have you figured this out yet? If not, try to simulate a memory warning on the iOS simulator. I was having a similar problem, and found out that the OS doesn't release the memory until it really needs it.

Answer (score 4):

What we can observe from the memory usage graph is that the tabViewController is not being dismissed properly and it builds up in the stack. While dismissing you have to allow the viewController which presented the tabViewController to dismiss it. It is its responsibility to dismiss. Also keep weak references for Outlets and assign any strong references to nil** in **viewWillDisapper:** . You can present a viewController modally as a temporary interruption to obtain important information from the user. If its not the case here, you can remove presenting modally. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852685/tabbar-memory-management). Hope this helps :)

Comment: I can't release it from memory manually, as I have ARC on. And even if I still have the method in the presented view controller, shouldn't  [self.presentingViewController dismiss... Have the same affect as having the method in the view controller doing the presenting? Because even when I do that it still doesn't go away from memory.

Comment: Also, these are completely different view controllers and need to be presented modally.

Comment: @ChrisLoonam You dont have to release it,just make sure you use weak reference and set it nil.